# Is real analytic function good enough (see problem)?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be real analytic and let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be such that the set $A'$ of all accomulation points od $A$ is not empty. If $f(a)=0$ for all $a \in A$ is then necessary $f(t)=0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ has a holomorphic extension to a neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}$, so the answer is yes by the unicity theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It is given by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Permanence), and  [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipleofPermanence.html), called "Principle of permanence"

Comment: I always thought this was called the "unicity theorem".

Comment: @GHfromMO, I think people "believed in" a "principle of permanence" for some time before the notion of holomorphic function was made explicit. And, more often these days I would call it "the identity principle"...